# Timing triggers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer

I'm trying to create a control method that executes submethods in separate threads.  I have looked into NSTimer, but a couple of the submethods are not being executed in an exact time interval.

Here are the 5 intervals:

1. Executes rapidly -- ~ every 0.1 seconds
2. Executes every 5 minutes
3. Executes every 10 minutes
4. Executes every hour on the hour
5. Executes every day on the day (at midnight)

Interval 1 - 3 should be very easy to do with the NSTimer.  Any tips for implementing the other ones?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is in OS X using the Foundation CLI

Comment: I had the first 3 implemented, but upon running it, the CPU usage of the app is considerably high.  Is this just how the NSTimer works? Would a simple while loop be more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (4) and (5), you want `dispatch_walltime`, if `NSTimer` isn't being accurate enough.

```
/* timespec for midnight, new years day 2014 */

struct tm time = {
   .tm_sec = 0,
   .tm_min = 0,
   .tm_hour = 0,
   .tm_mday = 1,
   .tm_mon = 1,
   .tm_year = 2014,
   .tm_wday = -1,  // I think -1 is wildcard here, can someone help?
   .tm_yday = -1,
   .tm_isdst = TRUE
};

const struct timespec whenToFire = {
   .tv_sec = mktime(time),
   .tv_nsec = 0
};

dispatch_time_t time = dispatch_walltime(&whenToFire,0);

/* a lower-priority queue may delay firing */    
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

dispatch_source_t timeSrc = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 
                                  0, 0, queue);

dispatch_source_set_timer(timeSrc, time, 100000 , 100);

dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timeSrc, ^{   
    /* only run once */
    static dispatch_once_t token;
    dispatch_once(&token, ^{
        /* code to run on New Years Day here */
        dispatch_source_cancel(timeSrc);
    });
});
```

Comment: It's not that the NSTimer isn't accurate enough, it's that the selector isn't executed on a periodic interval.  

Say, the program is started at 7:30.  I want method 4 to be executed at 8, 9, etc… I can't just use the timerWithTimeInterval method.

Comment: Yeah but you could use `– initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`  Both of these methods require you to schedule each run individually, but that's relatively easy, you just schedule the new one at the time the present one runs.

Comment: Actually `initWithFireDate` doesn't require you to schedule each run individually.  Just set one to fire at 4pm, set the interval to 3600 seconds.